# How to configure project including third-party project with its own build system

Tags: cmake, autotools

I have autotools project and I would like to add some third-party source code (libsoxr) with own cmake configuration. But I don't know what add to configure.ac and makefile.am.

I need execute this commands:

```
libsoxr/cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF
libsoxr/make
```

and than link libsoxr/src/libsoxr.a to my own code

Does somebody know anything about this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I happened to be in the same situation, and solved the issue using the [`AC_CONFIG_FILES`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Configuration-Files.html) macro in `configure.ac`. A simplified version of the code is:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES(mylib-build/Makefile:mylib/CMakeLists.txt,
  mkdir -p mylib-build ; cd mylib-build ;
  cmake \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$prefix \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE \
  ${srcdir}/mylib ; 
  if [test $? != 0 ] ; 
  then 
    AC_MSG_ERROR([mylib: Cmake configuration failed. Check the error message above.])
  fi 
  cd ..
  , prefix=$prefix CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE
)
```

In `Makefile.am` I just added `mylib-build` as a sub-directory:

```
SUBDIRS = mylib-build
```

Note that I am by no means an auto-tools expert, so that this solution may not be the cleanest possible.